# Android toolbar menu is not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to add a menu to the ToolBar.
`onCreateOptionsMenu` method of my `Activity` is called, but no menu appears.

This is dashboard.xml (from menu folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.app.android.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_scan_qr"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:title="@string/menu_scan_qr"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

NOTE: icon of this menu is darker than the background color of the action bar, so it should be visible.

Inflating menu in Activity:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

    return true;
}
```

And the main theme for the application:

```
<style name="Theme.Application.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Theme.Application.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

Why `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called but menu doesn't appears. I'm using `appcompat-v7:21.0.3`

EDIT:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentViewId());

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        if (toolbar == null) {
            throw new Error("Can't find tool bar, did you forget to add it in Activity layout file?");
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Try to add `android:orderInCategory="100"` in your xml item

Comment: What does your Activity's layout look like? Does it contain a Toolbar view and are you setting it to the activity via setSupportActionBar(toolbar)?

Comment: I'm using setSupportActionBar(toolbar) after inflating it from activity layout file.

Comment: Joan, orderInCategory doesn't help

Comment: Try to replace `return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));` instead of return true;

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but when I place everything related menu inflating in onCreateOptionsMenu method, everything works fine.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: It does work indeed, but why? What is the purpose of `inflate()`? The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) doesn't even mention this.

Comment: It could be just overlapping color problem. If your toolbar is black color and the menu text is also in black color, you can't really see it. Even overflow menu icon was also black :D (It happened in my case). Further dismay- if there are only one or two menu options, even menu button does not seem to work (because menu is already present in toolbar)

Comment: it will continuously create when ever it is clicked,So use this @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

Comment: thanks Bro it was surprisingly acting. fabulous  +1 for you

Comment: Do you really call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) and not super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)?

Comment: It will loop the options menu

Comment: Should be returning "true" at the end: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus . Also the recommendation is to override onCreateOptionsMenu instead of onPrepareOptionsMenu.

Answer (score 45):

I was also facing the same problem, but the actual error was, i forgot to introduce toolbar in java activity

under `AppCompactActivity`, under on create method define your toolbar by id and call `setSupportActionBar(ToolBar);`

Example is below:

```
public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```

Comment: it is correct. i had the same problem. i did you said and it solved

Comment: i had everything set up but didnt use setSupportActionBar(ToolBar); 
introducing setSupportActionBar made the action button show up

Comment: Thanks you save my hours :)

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      tools:context="com.example.lolipoptest.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

and the Java Code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638089/appcompat-v7-toolbar-as-actionbar-not-showing-always-actions-from-menu-but-ap

Answer (score 8):

Do you have Toolbar in your dashboard layout ?. Call setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in your activity. Use Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme for the activities (If you are using toolbar in it)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class DashboardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Check your styles.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme" >
</style>

<color name="light">#FFBB33</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#FFBB33</color>
<color name="textColorPrimary">#FFBB33</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF8800</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#ff9977</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>

</resources>
```

Check your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="Hello Toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add theme in your activity in manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Not entirely true, the library adds the toolbar if not present and the right theme is used

Answer (score 8):

If you are inflating your menu from a fragment, e.g. by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, make sure to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreateView` of your fragment

Answer (score 6):

You need to inflate your menu in onCreateOptionsMenu of the activity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: Should be returning "true" at the end: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your toolbar initialization comes after adding the xml layout file
like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
 ....
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
 ....
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

to:

```
 ....
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
 ....
yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: This gives me exception: "This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."

Comment: this doesn't make sense, what is `yourapp:`suppose to be? the namespace `app:` is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `Toolbar` you need to set it as the support action bar in `onCreate`:

`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was stupid simple.
My toolbar was a child of AppBarLayout, and for some reason, when I was setting a Toolbar with Constraint layout, Toolbar's layout_width xml parameter was set to 0dp. So the toolbar was there, but invisible... (>_<)

So, if nothing from above helped you, just check "layout_width" and "layout_height" parameters.

Hope this will save someone's time :)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the answer, Hope this will save your a lot of code. You don't need to add `Toolbar` into the `XML` file if your parent theme is in the style, not a `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` , If you have `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` as a parent in your `theme.xml` or `style.xml`, Furthermore you can add a particular theme to your activity.

Step 1:  Create a `menu` folder under `res` if not exist and then create a menu item i.e item_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Setting"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
        android:id="@+id/action_setting"/>
</menu>
```

STEP 2: To show the menu on the default toolbar, add the below method in your `activity`

```
//To show or inflate menu on the toolbar
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.item_menu, menu)
        return true
    }
```

Step 3: To handle click events, add the below method.

```
//Handle the click event on the menu item option
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_setting -> {
                //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

NOTE: YOU DON'T NEED TO ADD A `TOOLBAR` INTO THE `XML` FILE.

Answer (score 1):

Another place to check that can disable the action bar is your themes. By default in Android Studio it gives you the Material3 light theme that does not support action bars. Replace that theme with one that does. You'll be able to find the folder at:

`res/values/themes/themes.xml`

Next in the file it should be on the same line as the:

`<style name="Base.Theme.<AppName>" parent="<Material3 or other theme that disables action bar>">`

And just replace the parent theme with one that does support action bars.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved when I changed it to app:showAsAction to android:showAsAction

Comment: nope, when you do this, and error will be show you.

Answer (score 0):

Add Icon you want under mipmap folder

[image: ic_menu_options]

Create menu_analysis.xml(under menu folder values.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.android.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity">
         <item
            android:id="@+id/action_scan_qr"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_options"
            android:title=""
            app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Now onPrepareOptionMenu under your Java class

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_analysis, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer does work, it causes my menu items rendered twice. As I've just worked around this, try somethings as:

1. remember to `return true;` instead of `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`
2. remember to set support action bar `setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))`
3. You might want to turn off default app title if you use customized toolbar: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Use setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in onCreate Method.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had written like,

```
MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
```

But, I changed the code like,

```
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
```

and it worked!

(I'm using kotlin and this code was written in Activity)

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Code

```
app:menu="menu_name"
```

Using java code

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
        
          private Toolbar toolbar;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.demo_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
  }
```

Full article on adding navigation icon , subtitle ,title , brand logo to the toolbar
you must go through
https://bedevelopers.tech/android-toolbar-implementation-using-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then try the following :

Add following line in `onCreateView()` method

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

Also add below line in `onViewCreated()` method

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.setSupportActionBar(customToolbar as Toolbar?)
```

Where customToolBar is the id of the toolbar added in xml file

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting `onCreateOptionsMenu` fixes the issue, but when you want to inject a different menu into Fragments then in the Activity, the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` methods are `Deprecated` there.

Instead, implement the new `MenuProvider` interface and link this menu provider in the Activity with `addMenuProvider()` and add a different `MenuProvider` in the `Fragment`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        addMenuProvider(MenuProvider())
    }

    private class MenuProvider : androidx.core.view.MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val menuHost: MenuHost = requireActivity()
        menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
            override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.trips, menu)
            }

            override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        }, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

    ...

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was overlapping of views, and click get over by another view. (ps. Check xml closely)

Answer (score -1):

Just try this under `onCreate`:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
```